# Docker daemon killed shorty after start

Tags: linux, docker, crash, systemd

I have a server running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with the latest updates. I installed docker-ce using the repo using the tutorial from https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

A short time after being started, the docker daemon is killed somehow. To debug, I ran

```
/usr/bin/dockerd
```

as root to get a log output:

```
root@hostname ~ # /usr/bin/dockerd
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:15.233508941+01:00] systemd-resolved is running, so using resolvconf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:15.235533437+01:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:15.235562227+01:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:15.235594491+01:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:15.235601292+01:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:15.239064773+01:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]  module=grpc
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:15.239098425+01:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:15.239155494+01:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42018d430, CONNECTING  module=grpc
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:15.239321579+01:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42018d430, READY  module=grpc
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:15.240106192+01:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]  module=grpc
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:15.240142826+01:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:15.240193046+01:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4207c2120, CONNECTING  module=grpc
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:15.240315657+01:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4207c2120, READY  module=grpc
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:15.243221391+01:00] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2 
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:15.275042317+01:00] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds 
WARN[2019-02-21T17:20:15.275313782+01:00] Your kernel does not support swap memory limit 
WARN[2019-02-21T17:20:15.275355076+01:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period 
WARN[2019-02-21T17:20:15.275369332+01:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime 
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:15.275785076+01:00] Loading containers: start.                   
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:16.335203892+01:00] Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address 
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:16.683066803+01:00] Loading containers: done.                    
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:16.835625998+01:00] Docker daemon                                 commit=6247962 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=18.09.2
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:16.835701364+01:00] Daemon has completed initialization          
INFO[2019-02-21T17:20:16.842961863+01:00] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock             
Killed
```

As you can see, there are two warnings (I think they are irrelevant) and one message about the killing in the end. The runtime of the daemon was about a minute.

I had docker installed previously on this machine (using docker.io), but I apt purged all packets, deleted all docker-related files in /var, /etc and /home and /run and performed a system-wide search for any file with `*docker*` in it. The issue still persists. How can I further debug and find out why the docker daemon is killed all the time?

Comment: This could be the issue: Your kernel does not support swap memory limit / Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period / Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime

Comment: I have several other machines running fine with these warnings. Also, according to [this](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004786934-Docker-service-shows-warnings-Your-kernel-does-not-support-cgroup-rt-runtime), the warnings should be irrelevant, as I don't have any container running and thus do not impose any limits on its memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Check /var/log/kern.log to see what reason docker daemon was killed. If it's about the OOM-killer (out-of-memory killer) triggered, you don't have enough memory on the system. Add more RAM or swap memory.

Comment: The kernel log doesn't show any entry when restarting docker (and getting it killed after that). `journalctl -f -k`also doesn't show any entries.